# Inno Setup compile output to text file

Tags: inno-setup

Using the Inno setup compiler UI, is there a way to print the compiler output text to a file from my script file? I want this text so I have a list of the files that were compressed during compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it does not include the entire log, from the sounds of it all you require is [this](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_outputmanifestfile.htm):

```
[Setup]
OutputManifestFile=filelist.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! As you said this doesn't print all compile info, but it logs the file names and other useful details.

Answer (score 2):

The basic editor (Compil32.exe) that comes with Inno Setup does not have the option to save the output log built in. As you have found you can copy the log and paste it in to a text file yourself.

However if you use one of the third party tools (Inno Script Studio (Disclaimer: I am the author of ISStudio), ISTool or InnoIDE) then all 3 have an option to allow the log to be saved to file automatically after the compile has been completed.

Comment: Inno Script Studio looks interesting! May I ask you if it's tied to a certain version of Inno Setup or it doesn't matter which version the user uses for compilation (or is it somehow embedded e.g.) ? [+1]

Comment: I've tested ISStudio with every version of Inno Setup from V4 to the latest. I will also work with either the ANSI or Unicode versions of Inno Setup v5

Answer (score 0):

I could not immediately find an option to save the output and I could not perform an selections on the data such as shift click or ctr-a but if you just right click on the data and click copy you get all of it and then just paste it into a new text file.

Comment: I was hoping to find a script option to do this automatically on compile, though this is a pretty simple way to get the output if no such option exists.